# Ember config file after build

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I want to take some config properties from a config file instead from index.html(not from the meta generated from config/environment), for example myConfig.js with two variables (lang and host) that can be changed after build. Currently I put that variables in config/enviroment, but i want to separate this variables from this data.

For example:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   ...
   <meta name="myapp/config/environment" content="%7B%22modulePrefix%22%3A%22user%22%2C%22environment%22%3A%22development%22%2C%22baseURL%22%3A%22/%22%2C%22locationType%22%3A%22auto%22%2C%22contentSecurityPolicy%22%3A%7B%22default-src%22%3A%22%27none%27%20localhost%22%2C%22script-src%22%3A%22%27self%27%20%27exportApplicationGlobal%22%3Atrue%7D">
   ...
   <script src="myconfig.js" ></script>
   ...
</html>
```

myconfig.js:

```
module.exports = function() {

   var MYCONFIG = {
       lang: 'en',
       host: 'http://.....'
   }

   return MYCONFIG ;
};
```

How this can be done?

Any help will be greatly appriciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I put a json file in the public folder and use Ember.$.ajax in the app route to get it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `config` utils

```
// utils/config-utils.js
export default {
 lang: 'en',
 host: 'http://.....'
};
```

and then import it where you need:

```
// controllers/my-controller.js
import ConfigUtil from '../utils/config';

const {
 lang
} = ConfigUtil;

export default MyController.extend({
   ...
});
```

Comment: How to separate the config-utils.js file from the rest of the builded code(myapp.js). I want my client to modify config values without having to rebuild the code (in fact he will not have the source code of the application, even the knowledge or tools to do it). Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood your question and didn't get that point. The solution I've posted didn't handle that situation